# AngularJS 1.3 - Display content of drop-down depending on selection in another drop-down menu

Tags: angularjs

I am wondering on how to setup the following data structure in two separate drop-down menus where the content of the second drop-down menu depends on the selection of the first menu. 
My structure is:

`{
    level1a:{
                Item1, 
                Item2,
                Item3,
                Item4
                },
    level1b:{
                Item5, 
                Item6,
                Item7,
                Item8
                }
}`

I would like to have the following procedure:

If I select in the first menu "level1a" then only the content Item1,.., Item4 should appear in the second drop-down menu, accordingly for the selection of the selection of "level1b". I was wondering if there is a "filter option on a previous button".
Does somebody know how to set this up? Any help would be much appreciated !

Cheers,
Andi

Comment: which drop-down are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Using [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) you can call a function when the first selection is done, then set the data for the second selection within that function

In controller:

```
$scope.choice = ['a','b']

$scope.a = ['Item1','Item2','Item3','Item4'];
$scope.b = ['Item5','Item6','Item7','Item8'];

$scope.data = [];

  $scope.change = function(choice) {
    if (choice == 'a'){
      $scope.data = $scope.a;
    } else {
      $scope.data = $scope.b;
    }   
};
```

IN HTML:

```
<select ng-model="selection" ng-change="change(selection)">
  <option value="">---Please select---</option> 
  <option value="a">Option 1</option>
  <option value="b">Option 2</option>
</select><br>

<select ng-model="selectionTwo">
  <option ng-repeat="option in data" value="{{option}}">{{option}}</option>
</select>
```

I was going to provide a plunker, but was unable to save it, don't know why.. I will edit if it resolves

edit: managed to save [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FTunY52XdmNAketNynFN?p=preview)